# HighCharts. How to dynamically set ticks and display labels relative to text in labels?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I dynamically set ticks through the **tickPositioner** and labels through the **labels.formatter**. With a narrow screen width, I need to display fewer ticks and labels so that everything fits.

I want to get the width of the label.  So I can calculate the step.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnbaqwce/[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
            var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks,
                ticksPositions = this.xAxis[0].tickPositions,
                tick0x,
              tick1x,
              getPosition = function (tick) {
                var axis = tick.axis;
                return Highcharts.Tick.prototype.getPosition.call(tick, axis.horiz, tick.pos, axis.tickmarkOffset);
              };

          tick0x = getPosition(ticks[ticksPositions[0]]).x;
          tick1x = getPosition(ticks[ticksPositions[1]]).x;

          this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.translate((tick1x - tick0x) / 12)
            }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    tickPositioner: function () {
      var positions = [],
          tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
          increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

      if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
        for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
          positions.push(tick);
        }
      }
      return positions;
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
        return this.value + "%$$$";
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 100.20, 200.30]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to get the label width which you can use in your calculations.

```
if(this.ticks[tick]) {
  console.log(this.ticks[tick].label.getBBox().width)
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15msykgw/

Comment: I have a tickPositioner locally called once, but twice in your example. Ticks object is empty. I can not repeat on the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jwtsvygq/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwtsvygq/4/

The ticks object is empty due to the fact that:
1. The chart width and height in percent.
2. Enabled styledMode option.

As a result, the following condition does not work out:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/e15e3e56faca7902844e19006c4c6f3d5adf5b0f/ts/parts/Chart.ts#L254356faca7902844e19006c4c6f3d5adf5b0f/ts/parts/Chart.ts#L2543

Comment: Actually what give you the label width? In tickPositioner, you can only render an array of ticks which will be displayed - you are not able to manipulate the distance between ticks

Comment: You are right, but I can form an array with ticks regarding the width of the label. Let's say I have 20 labels. I take the width of the axis and divide it by the maximum width of the label. So I get the number of labels that are guaranteed to fit on the axis. From this number you can determine the number of ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing these calculations in tickPositioner I think that a better solution will be:

1. get the widest label width,
2. divide axis width by above label width,
3. do an update on axis with floored output from above

   ```
   function(chart){
   let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
       labelWidth = xAxis.ticks[10].label.getBBox().width, // I choose tick 10 
       because is more wide
       axisWidth = xAxis.width,
       tickAmount = axisWidth / labelWidth;

       xAxis.update({
           tickAmount: tickAmount
       });
   }
   ```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/duegno8z/1/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickAmount

Comment: This does not work when the labels.useHTML option is enabled.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the case when this solution doesn't work? For me, the output is the same with the useHTML option. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sLt7xncp/